# Hash Table v/s Trees

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, tree, hashtable

Are hashtables always faster than trees? Though Hashtables have O(1) search complexity but suppose if due to badly designed hash function lot of collisions happen and if we handle collisions using chained structure (say a balanced tree) then the worst case running time for search would be O(log n). So can I conclude for big or small data sets even in case of worst case scenarios hash tables will always be faster than trees? Also If I have ample memory and I dont want range searches can I always go for a hash table?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I'd say it's situational. A lot of hashing functions are expensive, and for certain access patterns a tree is good.

Comment: "Always" is such a big all-encompassing word. Any chance you could edit this question to reduce it to something a bit more specific, like specific scenarios (only)? Otherwise it will almost certainly be closed as not-constructive.

Comment: Lot of people here have mentioned that the worst case would be O(N). How can it be O(n) if the collisions are handled using a balanced tree structure instead of a linked list. Worst case to search across a balanced tree like AVL would be O(log n)

Comment: @avinashshah You can reduce the worst case search case by using some other overflow data structure, but you don't get `O(lg n)` search for free. It comes at the cost of `O(lg n)` insert, since you are now inserting into a tree or similar that in the worst case contains all the elements. In almost all applications that trade off just isn't worth it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Are hashtables always faster than trees?

No, not *always*. This depends on many things, such as the size of the collection, the hash function, and for some hash table implementations - also the number of delete ops.

hash-tables are `O(1)` per op *on average* - but this is not always the case. They might be `O(n)` in *worst cases*.

Some reasons I can think of at the moment to prefer trees:

1. Ordering is important. [hash-tables are not maintaining order, BST is sorted by definition]
2. [Latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29) is an issue - and you cannot suffer the `O(n)` that might occur. [This might be critical for real-time systems]
3. Ther data might be "similar" related to your hash function, and many elements hashed to the same locations [collisions] is not unprobable. [this can be sometimes solved by using a different hash function]
4. For relatively small collections - many times the hidden constant between hashtable's `O(1)` is much higher then the tree's - and using a tree might be faster for small collections.

However - if the data is huge, latency is not an issue and collisions are unprobable - hash-tables are asymptotically better then using a tree.

Comment: It's often the case that carefully packed trees can out perform a hash table due to cache coherency (be it from main memory or disk). It doesn't matter how much data you have in this case -- hash tables may not be your best option depending on how you're using the dictionary structure.

Comment: What hash tables ? Open Addressing Hash Tables or "Bucket" Hash Tables ? With or without incremental resizing ? Or Linear Hashing based ? There *so many* implementations of hash tables around! Your answer is wrong for some of them, so please, be precise.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: These are traditional drawbacks for pretty much all hash tables, even if using open addressing or chaining with a simple array as the "bucket". Ordering is drawback because hashing does not guarantee order will be remained. Latency is an issue due to worst case (if you cannot suffer any `O(n)` ops due to some constraints - it is an issue), similar hash value is not really a draw back since it can be easily resolved with choosing a different hash function, and the size issue is usually due to hash functions overhead if I remember correctly. What specifically you have problem with?

Comment: @amit: No, they are not (apart from ordering... obviously). *Latency*, for example, is ill-defined here. I can guarantee O(1) insertion with a hash table (using incremental resizing) whereas for a BST I'll have regular rebalancing acts so O(log N) worst case. O(1) lookup however is impossible to guarantee; but I can get O(log N) by using a BST as the bucket structure. *Small* collections can similary benefit from Open Addressing hash tables: smaller per-node overhead, single block allocation => better CPU cache behavior than a BST! So... not all comments apply equally to all implementations.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Ok, I see what you meant. Indeed, there is no silver bullet, and yes - there are work-arounds to address some issues of the 'traditional' DS (such as BST as bucket), and indeed none equally applies for all, but these are some issues which should be considered when choosing the DS for your set.

Comment: @amit: Yes, I agree. My basic recommendation would be to go with BST. It's simpler. Works well and reliably. And let's worry about the tradeoff when performance matters, we'll have more info then :)

Answer (score 1):

If due to badly designed hash function lot of collisions happen and if we handle collisions using chained structure (say a balanced tree) then the worst case running time for search would be **O(n)** (not O(log n)). Therefore you cannot conclude for big or small data sets even in case of worst case scenarios hash tables will always be faster than trees.

Answer (score 0):

Use hashtable, and init it with the proper dimension. For example if you use only half space the collisions are very few.

Answer (score 0):

In worst case scenario you'll have O(n) time in hast-tables. **But** this is a billions less probable then sun exploding write now, so when using a good hash-function you can safely assume it works in O(1) unless sun explodes.
On the other hand, performance of both Hash-Tables and Trees can vary on implementation, language, and phase of the moon, so the only good answer to this question is "Try both, *think* and  pick better".