# Selection of map or unordered_map based on keys's type

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, data-structures, c++11

A generally asked question is whether we should use unordered_map or map for faster access.
The most common( rather age old ) answer to this question is:
If you want direct access to single elements, use unordered_map but if you want to iterate over elements(most likely in a sorted way) use map.

Shouldn't we consider the data type of key while making such a choice?
As hash algorithm for one dataType(say int) may be more collision prone than other(say string).

If that is the case( the hash algorithm is quite collision prone ), then I would probably use map even for direct access as in that case the O(1) constant time(probably averaged over large no. of inputs) for unordered_map map be more than lg(N) even for fairly large value of N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You raise a good point... but you are focusing on the wrong part.

The problem is not the type of the key, per se, but on the hash function that is used to derive a hash value for that key.

Lexicographical ordering is **easy**: if you tell me you want to order a structure according to its 3 fields (and they already support ordering themselves) then I'll just write:

```
bool operator<(Struct const& left, Struct const& right) {
    return boost::tie(left._1,  left._2,  left._3)
         < boost::tie(right._1, right._2, right._3);
}
```

And I am done!

However writing a hash function is **difficult**. You need some knowledge about the distribution of your data (statistics), you might need to prevent specially crafted attacks, etc... Honestly, I do not expect many people of being able to craft a good hash function. But the worst part is, *composition is difficult too*! Given two independent fields, combining their hash value *right* is hard (hint: `boost::hash_combine`).

So, indeed, if you have no idea what you are doing and you are treating user-crafted data, just stick to a `map`. It's maybe slower (not sure), but it's safer.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really such a thing as *collision prone object*, because this thing is dependent on the hash function you use. Assuming the objects are not identical - there is some feature that can be utilized to create an informative hash function to be used.

Assuming you have some knowledge on your data - and you know it is likely to have a lot of collision for some hash function `h1()` - then you should find and use a different hash function `h2()` which is better suited for this task.

---

That said, there are other issues as well why to favor tree based data structures over hash bases (such as latency and the size of the set), some are covered by [my answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10033515/572670).

Answer (score 1):

There's no point trying to be too clever about this.  As always, profile, compare, optimise if useful.  There are many factors involved - quite a few of which aren't specified in the Standard and will vary across compilers.  Some things may profile better or worse on specific hardware.  If you are interested in this stuff (or paid to pretend to be) you should learn about these things a bit more systematically.  You might start with learning a bit about actual hash functions and their characteristics.  It's extremely rare to be unable to find a hash function that has - for all practical purposes - no more collision proneness than a random but repeatable value - it's just that sometimes it's slower to approach that point than it is to handle a few extra collisions.